# AFNetworking and download speed throttling

Tags: objective-c, afnetworking, throttling

I'd like to know if anyone of you guys did a download speed throttling with the use of AFNetworking framework. My app uses AFN to download large files and I'd like to introduce a speed limit feature as well.

My best guess it to sleep the operation inside AFURLConnectionOperation method `connection:(NSURLConnection *) connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data`? If this is the right approach, how to best implement it to avoid any timeouts etc.
Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: Download using normal speed and then call `NSThread.sleep` :)

Answer (score 1):

I've tried using this method but its not much promising.

If you use sleep etc in `connection:didReceiveData:` of NSURLConnection, it receives the data and fills its buffer(1MB approx. in max delay with full speed net) and then calls `connection:didReceiveData:`. With this you will give spikes of net usage. I don't think this is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You could use two different techniques to throttle your network :

- Use Apple's "Network Link Conditioner"

  - if you are testing on a developer enabled device : Go to "Settings" > "Developer" > "Network Link Conditioner", the switch to Enable and choose a profile
  - if you are testing on the Simulator, which would use you Mac's own network connection, you can download the "Network Link Conditioner" prefpane for OSX (See [Mattt's article here on NSHipster](http://nshipster.com/network-link-conditioner/))
- Or [use `OHHTTPStubs`](https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHHTTPStubs) which can both **stub your requests** with some fake data (very useful for testing, including generating some error cases not easily reproducible in real life), but also **introduce a delay in the response** and **fake network latency and slow networks**. (You may search Google for examples on using it using AFNetworking, there are plenty of articles about it)